# Platforms for testing automated trading?

Tags: api, platform, stock

a.) Are there any websites, tools, etc. that are platforms for testing stock trading applications?
b.) Are there any platforms apis etc that allow automated trading?

Any thoughts?

Also, i particularly like coding in python.

Comment: Just an FYI, if you are talking high-freq trading: In the area of competition we had to squeeze max performance with C++ doing all possible optimizations on Linux like lock-free collections pre-allocated pools and avoided using objects altogether to bypass VMTs to get maximum throughput per ms. If you use Python then you will lag 10x fold. We also used Erlang for multi-node orchestration in cluster. The front end to visualize we did in C# where I could not use "regular" objects like DataTables and GridViews because they were not fast enough and lagged. I needed to process 25000 trades/sec

Comment: yeah i wont be doing anything near that fast, thanks though. How did you test your app/ program?

Comment: @itadapter I also worked for a high-frequency trading componey, where every tiny bit of performance was crucial (-> C++). There seem to be other players, however, that use less time-demanding strategies. For example, some develop parts of their algorithms in Matlab from what I heard.

Comment: Yes they do, I heard someone even used VB6 :). It's all about your throughput and how much revenue you can trade-out of crazy stream. My GUI front-end connected to like 10 Linux Servers runing Erlang control nodes and strategies coded in GCC. Each node fed 1000-3000/transactions per second that I had to re-aggregate in grids and scrolling graphs. All I can say is that I spent a few days scratching my head to trick CLR garbage collector not to enagage basically had to recycle objects and used pre-allocated struct pools. Crazy stuff but we peaked at 50,000/sec coming from raw sockets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RTS Realtime Systems](http://www.rtsgroup.net/trading) is a well-known trading platform. It is written in Java, though.

When you are searching for testing tools, try to search for the term backtesting and algorithmic trading. I came up with this result: [PyAlgoTrader](http://gbeced.github.com/pyalgotrade/)

Answer (score 4):

[Quantopian](https://www.quantopian.com/) is a great solution. It lets you upload and test your algorithms on large data sets, while keeping them private or sharing with the community.

Comment: And Quantopian is in python, which the op would be happy with.